# Twilio Programmable video - Dominant view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, twilio, twilio-video

I am using the iOS SDK to create a video chat app with ~25 - 50 participants per call. I have currently been able to add local and remote participants to the main view like shown in current.

Now, I want the user to be able to click on a participant thumbnail (which is a video) and replicate that participant’s video stream on the gray section.

[image: A picture to Explain]

What is the best way to achieve this? I tried the below piece of code, but it seems to remove the remote participant from the scrollable view in the bottom, and add it to the gray section, leaving a gap, while what I want is a duplication. Here’s my code on didSelect

````
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let viewToAdd = remoteParticipantViews[indexPath.row] as ParticipantView
        viewToAdd.frame = self.dominantVideo.bounds
        self.dominantVideo.addSubview(viewToAdd)
    }
}```
````

Comment: try going through `https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-ios` sample app